Extracting power from environment

Why when somebody mentions heatengine to heatpump you draw it like closed system and not like this?
Assuming using something with lower boiling point than water as coolant #2, why this wouldn't work, or atleast improve efficiency of generators?
Also condenser is being cooled, I did expect it's what condenser is by default.

Your graphic is hard  or not to understand. for example the coolant Nr 2 why should it be water?  Where is the water wich you want to heat with the heat exchanger?

I need lower boiling point, to achieve pressure at ambient temperature, let it be 23˚C which is normal temperature of sea water.

I don' understand your answer. Water is usually not used as coolant in a machine. And do you want to cool air or heat it?

I want cool air to produce energy.

Condenser is also assumed having environmental temperature, or it's cold point of another heat pump.

In common powerplant, water is used exactly to evaporate and run steam turbine.

@trula, Not only is water the usual working fluid in a large base-load thermal power station, but water also is frequently used to cool the primary loop's condenser. When you see great clouds of steam billowing out from a plant's hyperbolic cooling towers that's water from the environment, evaporating to cool the secondary loop water, that was used to condense the primary loop steam back to water.

That's high temperature, I want to keep pressure at low temperature.

"Why when somebody mentions heat engine to heat pump you draw it like closed system and not like this?" By definition, a closed system doesn't exchange mass with its surroundings. It looks to me what you have drawn is a closed system (albeit a flawed one, per the answer by naturallyinconsistent)

This has already been tried.  It is called OTEC, and it has a VERY low thermodynamic energy efficiency due to the very low temperature differences involved.  Very low efficiency leads to very low economic performance, so this type of system will not be in widespread use.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocean_thermal_energy_conversion

They don't heat pump there. I was trying to contact them to reveal their internal workings, how do they extract it but I failed.

Thermoelectric devices have effectivity measured microwatts per meter kelvin, but you can stack them. Connecting them in thermal series but parallel electrical circuits can be really good. I can't wait until they are nanotech that maximizes it.

You have some mistakes in your diagram that makes it easy to get lost arguing about them. However, the essence of your question is really just that you have not learnt about entropy, and the sadness that is the 2nd law of thermodynamics. Your scheme is in direct violation of that. i.e. you have violated known physics, even if it is new to you, and so there is no way it can work.
One of the biggest and most obvious mistakes, is that a heat exchanger always has two inputs and two outputs, for a total of four arrows. You have drawn them with three arrows. But I digress.
Yes, it is definitely possible to use mechanical energy and the expander and compressor to create a temperature difference so as to run a heat engine. The problem is that we can prove that you can never use this temperature difference to even recoup the initial mechanical energy you input, let alone generate more than what you started with. So you have just drawn another attempt at a perpetual motion machine, and it is doomed to fail.

Can you please cite those laws of thermodynamics where I broke it?

Also it's two different heat exchangers, and total arrows if it was monad is not 4... Can you read?

I think you have confused the words "sadness" with "joy", for further help, please, see https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/joy

Your diagram is difficult to follow, but systems already exist that extract energy from temperature differences in the environment. Geothermal energy systems utilise locations in the earth's crust where the temperature is higher than at the surface, whereas ocean thermal energy systems utilise the opposite temperature gradient that exists between warm surface waters and cold water in the ocean depths. Not all of these are closed systems.

Those systems harvest temperature gradients, this system also creates gradient it harvests.

@FuzzySystem The laws of thermodynamics tell us you cannot extract more energy from a temperature gradient than was used to create it in the first place. If you are hoping to extract energy from a temperature gradient that the system creates rather than from a pre-existing natural temperature gradient then you are trying to create a perpetual motion machine.

Laws of thermodynamics speaks about closed systems, this is not one.

@FuzzySystem So your system is not open since it does not utilise an existing temperature gradient, but it is not closed either. I don't think there is a third alternative !

It's open, because it uses enviroment as almost infinite reservoir of thermal energy. Remember, there's more thermal energy in glacier than a cup of coffe.

@FuzzySystem Then, just as my answer says, you have not made it clear how your idea differs from existing geothermal and ocean thermal energy systems. We seem to be going round in circles, so I am done here.
